# EF Cannot remove object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, db-first

In my model I have similar tables:

- `Persons (ID-NAME)` e.g. (1-Paul - 2-Frank - 3-George)
- `Roles (ID-NAME)` e.g. (1-Admin - 2-Developer - 3-Junior)
- `Persons_Roles (ID_PERSON Not Null` - ID_ROLE Not Null e.g. (1-1 - 1-2 - 2-3 - 2-1 - 3-2)

Table `Persons_Roles` has a foreign key on both `Persons` and `Roles` tables.

I need to delete a role. I actually do

```
Persons oP = DbContext.Persons.Single(p=>p.ID == 1);
Persons_Roles oR = oP.Persons_Roles.Single(p=>p.ID_ROLE == 2);
oP.Persons_Roles.Remove(oR);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I get this error

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Why am I getting this error and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: *I need to delete a role* -- Do you really mean a `Role` or a `Person_Role`?

Comment: Hi, a Person_Role not a Role, i typed wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete a rule, you must first delete all the records that are refrenced to that rule.
For example, you must first clear all the records in the Person_Roles table and then delete the rule from Role Table

```cs
var personRoles = DbContext.Persons_Roles.Where(p=>p.ID_ROLE == 2).ToList();
DbContext.Persons_Roles.RemoveRange(personRoles);
var role = DbContect.Roles.Single(a=>a.ID==2);
DbContext.Roles.Remove(role);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i meant i want to delete a PERSON_ROLE not a role. The issue is in the first part of your code: DbContext.Persons_Roles.RemoveRange(personRoles); That's where i get the error.

Comment: @Fudo No, that's exactly what you should do, not `oP.Persons_Roles.Remove(oR);`. When you remove from `oP.Persons_Roles` EF will try to set a FK to null, whereas removing from `DbContext.Persons_Roles` will delete the record.

Comment: I now see what you mean. Thanks not it's ok !

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete data if which is referenced to another table as foreign key, but you done through

Remove value from referenced table after then you can able to perform delete operation only

Comment: Hi, sortry i meant i want to delete a PERSON_ROLE not a role.